# Including math environment in tick labels from newcommand with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros

I am writing a book, and it will include many figures with the same x-axis.  In order to keep each figure consistent across chapters I am trying to define a series of commands to typeset the axes.  I very new to extending LaTeX, and even more new to pgf/tikz.

When I try to put symbols or math commands in the tick labels argument of my axis I get the following error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.14       ]
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

  \newcommand{\xpiaxis}[0]{
          xtick={0,1},%
          xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{4}$}%
  }
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        \xpiaxis
      ]
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{xpiaxis/.style={% instead of command define style ...
      xtick={0,1},%
      xticklabels={,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{4}$}%
                    }
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xpiaxis  % here commands are not alowed
      ]
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For my own edification where can I use new commands vs your method?

Comment: commands cannot be used as styles in `tikz` and `pgfplots`. anywhere else they should work as expected. even inside of `tikz` or `pgfplots` as element of picture (but not as style).