# Fully show a x-label on tikz figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I have produced the following code, for a graph I am making:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{AMD top 10 SBP peers (2016)}
\label{FigAMDtop10SBPpeers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=8,
    ylabel = Annual Search Fraction,
    yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    symbolic x coords={Intel,HP,Nvidia,Broadcom,Texas Instruments,Google,Microsoft,IBM},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot[ybar,fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135}] coordinates {
        (Intel,6.1529271206690564)
        (HP,1.3888888888888888)
        (Nvidia,1.045400238948626)
        (Broadcom,0.9557945041816009)
        (Texas Instruments,0.9109916367980884)
        (Google,0.6869772998805257)
        (Microsoft,0.6571087216248507)
        (IBM,0.6421744324970132)

    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which looks like:

[image]

Clearly, the x-labels are not appropriate. I was wondering if there is a way to make the entire x label visible, without rotating the label (i don't like the layout)? For a firm like Texas Instruments, which has 2 words, maybe put the second word on the line below?

EDIT: The possible solution is not what I am looking for, since that merely shifts every other label downwards. This is not what I want; I want to keep the label positionings next to each other.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, as I don't want every other label to be pushed downwards.

Comment: You said *maybe* put the second word on the line below, not that that was a requirement.  Regardless, please make your example compilable, thanks.

Comment: So you want to keep the labels at the same spot and in the same orientation but still get rid of the overlap? The only degree of freedom left is scaling them but that is not a good idea (after all people should be able to read them). What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: apparently you like to store elephant into lady handbag ... with your restriction you not have many option: reduce font size, increase image width, use abbreviation (TI for Texas Instruments) ... or simply relax your restrictions :-)

Comment: Despite being pretty new to LaTeX, I was thinking of using a line break, like you can do in text? i.e. \\ with the label, but I have not been able to find any solutions to this.

Comment: Were you thinking about breaking "Microsoft" and "Google" into two lines as well?

Answer (score 1):

With code borrowed from [Including math environment in tick labels from newcommand with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433219/including-math-environment-in-tick-labels-from-newcommand-with-tikz)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{xpiaxis/.style={% instead of command define style ...
        xtick={0,...,8},%
        xticklabels={Intel,HP,Nvidia,Broadcom,\parbox{1in}{\centering{}Texas\\Instruments}}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{AMD top 10 SBP peers (2016)}
\label{FigAMDtop10SBPpeers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    ymin=0, ymax=8,
    ylabel = Annual Search Fraction,
    yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    xpiaxis]
    \addplot[ybar,fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135}] coordinates {
        (1,6.1529271206690564)
        (2,1.3888888888888888)
        (3,1.045400238948626)
        (4,0.9557945041816009)
        (5,0.9109916367980884)
        (6,0.6869772998805257)
        (7,0.6571087216248507)
        (8,0.6421744324970132)

    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```